# wp_cron not running in my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I've created a Wordpress plugin that needs to run a cron job.
In the plugin I have successfully set up the cron job and the schedule and I can see it in the admin using the WP Crontrol plugin.

The problem is that when the scheduled event is due to run, it simply does nothing. It does not run the function in the plugin. But if I move the function that is due to run into the theme's functions.php file then it runs and works perfectly.

So the question is - why does wp_cron not check the plugin for the function to run???

Here is the code that works in functions.php but does nothing when in the plugin:

```
function swd_setup_schedule() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'swd_hourly_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'ten_minutes', 'swd_hourly_event');
    }
}

add_action( 'swd_hourly_event', 'swd_do_this_hourly' );

function swd_do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
    update_option( 'swd_recur_test1', 'test_value_' . date('d-m-Y g:i') );
    add_option( 'swd_recur_test' . date('d-m-Y g:i'), '_value_' . date('d-m-Y g:i') );
}
```

Comment: Where in the plugin? Index.php?

Comment: No it is within another file. Will that make a difference? I will give it a try

Comment: Unless you're including the other file from index.php it won't be available.

Comment: Yeah it is being included but I put the code in index.php and it is working now! Thanks @pguardiario